# Adding time in Excel, for a bus timetable

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am constructing a bus timetable.

I am starting with a base time of 9am (*Cell B2*), with irregular intervals:

```
    B         C         D
2  09:00    10:30     12:00
3  09:05
4  09:12
5  10:14
6  10:20
```

When the bus comes back to the depot it will depart again at 10:30 (*Cell C2*), and 12:00 (*Cell D2*) the third time.

Is there a formula so that the time intervals given in rows B2:B6, can be mimicked in rows C3:C6, and D3:D6?

I can PM image if needed!

Answer (score 1):

Type in **C3**:

```
= $B3 - $B2 + C2
```

`$B3 - $B2` gets the time interval from 1 stop to the other, and `+ C2` is to add this time interval to `C2`.

Copy this formula to **C3:D6** to complete the table.

Answer (score 0):

On **C3** put `=$C$2+(B3-$B$2)` and copy and paste the formula to all the cells you need  on columns C and D.